# PHP Switch-statement using MySQL Query result

Tags: php, mysql, return-value, switch-statement

To make my life a bit easier, I created a function DoQuery:

```
// DoQuery
function DoQuery($sql)
{
    global $cm_db_host,$cm_db_user,$cm_db_pass,$cm_db_name;
    $con = mysql_connect($cm_db_host,$cm_db_user,$cm_db_pass);
    if(!$con) return 1001;
    $db = mysql_select_db($cm_db_name);
    if(!$db) return 1002;
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$res) return 1003;
    return $res;
    mysql_close();
}
```

The function works perfectly - it seems..

Here is how I use it:

```
 $res = DoQuery("UPDATE table SET column1='value 1',column2='value 2' WHERE id=1;");

 switch($res){
    case true:
      echo 'Response[success]ENDCMTAG';
      break;
    case 1001:
      die('Response[dberror1001]ENDCMTAG\r\n'.
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;
    case 1002:
      die('Response[dberror1002]ENDCMTAG\r\n'.
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;
    case 1003:
      die('Response[dberror1003]ENDCMTAG\r\n'.
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;  
 }
```

Now, when I purposely screw up the SQL statement, so `case 1003` should be used, the `case true` is what is being executed.

According to the PHP manual (yes, I did look it up! ;) ) a MySQL INSERT, UPDATE .... will either return true or false. In my DoQuery function, whenever a MySQL function returns false, I output specific error codes instead, so I know where it went wrong. If no error occurs, `$res` should be true, and then the `case true` should be executed, right?

The problem is that it always outputs true, even if I change the SQL query to rubbish.

If I put the `case true` at the bottom of the switch, the `case 1001` is always executed **when everything goes OK** - I know because I check the `mysql_error()` field, and its empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just as a side note, you shouldn't be creating a connection every time you want to do a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the value `1003`, which evaluates to a "truthy" value when compared against a boolean.  It will always evaluate to `TRUE`.

```
// Essentially it is this:
if (1003) {
   // I'm TRUE!!!
}
```

You cannot use a strict comparison `===` either, since in the true case, you are returning a MySQL result resource, not the boolean `TRUE`.

If you rearrange your `switch()` so that the valid resource case is at the bottom, your error cases will be correctly evaluated first.

```
 switch($res){
    case 1001:
      die('Response[dberror1001]ENDCMTAG\r\n'.
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;
    case 1002:
      die('Response[dberror1002]ENDCMTAG\r\n'.
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;
    case 1003:
      die('Response[dberror1003]ENDCMTAG\r\n'.
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;  

    // Valid result is the default case.
    default:
      echo 'Response[success]ENDCMTAG';
      break;
 }
```

However, this is a little weird and could cause problems if your function ever returns a different error value (if it is changed,) but the switch isn't updated.  Instead, you should check for a true/false return on the value first and then pass it to the switch to evaluate error codes:

```
// Check if we have an Integer value. If we do, its an error code!
// If not, it's a result, or true!
if (is_int($res)) {
 switch($res){
    case 1001:
      die('Response[dberror1001]ENDCMTAG\r\n'.
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;
    case 1002:
      die('Response[dberror1002]ENDCMTAG\r\n'.
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;
    case 1003:
      die('Response[dberror1003]ENDCMTAG\r\n'.
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;  
 }
 // $res was valid. Success!
 else {
   // handle your valid results
 }
```

Comment: @Jeff see my the later addition to check the true case outside the switch

Comment: Tried your last code - it is now always true even if I mess with the Statement. :S

Comment: @Jeff Foolish me.  Changed to `if (!is_int($res))` since you're returning an integer value or the result resource. Sorry

Comment: So, if $res is not of type int, enter the switch? Isnt it supposed to be if $res IS int? :)

Comment: Yeah, its the other way around, just tested it. :) `iff(is_int ...` is what should be used :)

Comment: Michael, I edited your answer to make the code work, also rephrased the comment describing what is happening. Hope you dont mind! :)

Comment: I'm so far off my game this morning.  :) Glad you're sorted out.

Comment: Hahah, it happens for everyone every once in awhile :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Switch statements always do loose comparison.

So any number (but 0) will also evaluate to `True`.

Another improvement I would have on your code is make use of constants for the error codes.

```
define('QUERY_RESULT_SUCCESS', '1000');
define('QUERY_RESULT_CONNECTION_FAILED', '1001');
define('QUERY_RESULT_SELECTDB_FAILED', '1002');
define('QUERY_RESULT_QUERY_FAILED', '1003');

function DoQuery($sql)
{
    global $cm_db_host,$cm_db_user,$cm_db_pass,$cm_db_name;
    $con = mysql_connect($cm_db_host,$cm_db_user,$cm_db_pass);
    if(!$con) return QUERY_RESULT_CONNECTION_FAILED;
    $db = mysql_select_db($cm_db_name);
    if(!$db) return QUERY_RESULT_SELECTDB_FAILED;
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$res) return QUERY_RESULT_QUERY_FAILED;
    return QUERY_RESULT_SUCCESS;
    mysql_close();
}

 $res = DoQuery("UPDATE table SET column1='value 1',column2='value 2' WHERE id=1;");

 switch($res){
    case QUERY_RESULT_SUCCESS:
      echo 'Response['.QUERY_RESULT_SUCCESS.']ENDCMTAG';
      break;
    case QUERY_RESULT_CONNECTION_FAILED:
      die('Response['.QUERY_RESULT_CONNECTION_FAILED.']ENDCMTAG'."\r\n".
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;
    case QUERY_RESULT_SELECTDB_FAILED:
      die('Response['.QUERY_RESULT_SELECTDB_FAILED.']ENDCMTAG'."\r\n".
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;
    case QUERY_RESULT_QUERY_FAILED:
      die('Response['.QUERY_RESULT_QUERY_FAILED.']ENDCMTAG'."\r\n".
      'MySQLError['.mysql_error().']ENDCMTAG\r\n');
      break;  
 }
```

Also note the double quotes around the `\r\n` since it has to be evaluated.

Comment: If this is to be used for a query returning a result set, it doesn't return the resource in any way from which results could be fetched. Fine for `INSERT/UPDATE` though

Comment: It is to be used for INSERT and UPDATES :)

Comment: @Michael: see the OP's question :)